# Grep - Search for an actual fixed string

Tags: grep

I'm trying to match a fixed pattern/string:

```
print
int
```

In this example, using `grep -F 'int'` or `grep -F "int"` one would normally get the "fixed" string, with the -F flag...

But it match both string in this example (instead of only matching the line with `int` without `print`).

And while it seems that many other post have a similar goal/question, *it is clearly showed here that the -F flag that is recommended on said post, doesn't work*.

How can i match an actual fixed string with grep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-F` just turns off the interpretation of characters like `.` and `*` as regular expression metacharacters, and instead treats them as string literals. It has no effect on whether the pattern matches substrings, whole words, or whole lines - for that you need the `-w` or `-x` flags:

> ```
>    -w, --word-regexp
>           Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
>           words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
>           at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
>           constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
>           of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
>           Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
>           underscore.  This option has no effect if -x is also specified.
>
>    -x, --line-regexp
>           Select  only  those  matches  that exactly match the whole line.
>           For a regular expression pattern, this  is  like  parenthesizing
>           the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.
> ```

Comment: the `-x` flag did the trick!

Comment: -x will only work if they will be on different lines:  echo 'int - print'|grep -x "int" wont help just fyi but you used \n so whatever :)

Comment: yeah, noticed! at least now, i know there multiple way to do this :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that 'int' also appears at the end of the word 'print'.

The use of -F fixed strings may simply be disabling regex search, but the fixed string 'int' is still in the word 'print'.

The solution may be to go back to using a regex, and specify you also want word boundaries for a 'whole words' search

```
echo -e 'int\nprint' | grep '\bint\b'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of:

```
echo -e 'int\nprint\print' |grep -P '(^|\s)\int(?=\s|$)'

echo 'int - print'|grep -E '(^|\s)int($|\s)'

echo 'int - print'|grep -Fw "int"
```